# installing tensorflow without internet connection

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, keras

I have to install TensorFlow + Keras on my computer, but I have not internet connection on it, so I have to download this package on another computer and then pass it on mine.

My question is: where can I saefty downolad TensorFlow + Keras and then, how can I install it using Anaconda?

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: For tensorflow follow this guide: https://github.com/amutu/tensorflow-offline

Answer (score 3):

I will just assume you are using a Linux machine

For tensorflow, you can follow the guide provided by florian.

**Step 1**
For Keras you just need to git clone or download the repository in https://github.com/keras-team/keras
Once you cloned or downloaded the repository on your machine connected to the internet, pass it to the one you want to use it one.

**Step 2**
Open a terminal and navigate to the passed keras folder with `cd`. run the setup.py by tipping `./setup.py` into the console and you are done.

**Step 3**
To verify the installation you can run one of the examples. Navigate to the examples folder inside the keras folder and type `./mnist_cnn.py`into the console. If everything was installed right you should see the network training and output. Otherwise, an error message will be displayed in the console.

Here is the windows version for keras and anaconda

**Step 1**
Copy the downloaded folder of keras to `%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`. Then use cd `%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras` to get to the keras folder.

**Step 2**
in the same terminal type `python setup.py develop` to install keras on windows.

**Step 3**
To check keras navigate into the examples folder and run the same example is in the Linux step 3.

My windows skills are very rusty, so I won't be able to help you troubleshoot problems here. I recommend you to install Linux on a second partition if you want to dive into deep learning since it is a lot easier to set up a system for DL on Linux than on Windows, also if you want to use AWS later it is chaper on Linux than windows.

Comment: I'm currently use Windows!

Comment: Can you help me to make the same thing in Windows?
Thanks a lot.